# Cauchy-Schwarz-like inequality involving 2-by-2 minors and symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, symmetric-matrices, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \geq 3$ be orthonormal vectors and let also $A,B$ be $n$-by-$n$ real symmetric matrices. From numerical experiments **it seems that the following inequality is true**: $$\left|\sum_{i,j,k}A_{ik}B_{jk}\begin{vmatrix}x_i & x_k \newline z_i & z_k \end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}y_j & y_k \newline z_j & z_k \end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}x_i & x_j \newline y_i & y_j \end{vmatrix}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\sum_{i,k}A_{ik}^2\begin{vmatrix}x_i & x_k \newline z_i & z_k \end{vmatrix}^2} \sqrt{\sum_{j,k}B_{jk}^2\begin{vmatrix}y_j & y_k \newline z_j & z_k \end{vmatrix}^2},$$
where every index in the triple and double sums runs from 1 to $n$. If it weren't for the one-half on the right-hand side, the proof would be a straightforward application of the triangle inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz, namely:
$$LHS \leq \sum_{i,j,k}\left|A_{ik}B_{jk}\left|\begin{smallmatrix}x_i & x_k \newline z_i & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right| \left|\begin{smallmatrix}y_j & y_k \newline z_j & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right| x_i y_j\right| + \sum_{i,j,k}\left|A_{ik}B_{jk}\left|\begin{smallmatrix}x_i & x_k \newline z_i & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right| \left|\begin{smallmatrix}y_j & y_k \newline z_j & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right| x_j y_i\right| \\ \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i,j,k}A_{ik}^2 \left|\begin{smallmatrix}x_i & x_k \newline z_i & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right|^2 y_j^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i,j,k}B_{jk}^2 \left|\begin{smallmatrix}y_j & y_k \newline z_j & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right|^2 x_i^2} + \sqrt{\sum_{i,j,k}A_{ik}^2 \left|\begin{smallmatrix}x_i & x_k \newline z_i & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right|^2 x_j^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i,j,k}B_{jk}^2 \left|\begin{smallmatrix}y_j & y_k \newline z_j & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right|^2 y_i^2} \\ = 2\sqrt{\sum_{i,k}A_{ik}^2 \left|\begin{smallmatrix}x_i & x_k \newline z_i & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{j,k}B_{jk}^2 \left|\begin{smallmatrix}y_j & y_k \newline z_j & z_k \end{smallmatrix}\right|^2},$$
where the triple sums reduced to double sums thanks to $x,y$ being norm-one vectors. However, this is 4 times larger than the right-hand side, so one has to proceed more carefully, but how? Any hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: When $i=j$ we get zero terms on the left that are non-zero on the right.

Comment: The RHS reminds me of some generalized Lagrange identity. Wouldn't be surprised if we can express it like $\sqrt{\|Ax\|^2 \|Az \|^2 - |\langle Ax, Az \rangle|^2}\sqrt{\|By\|^2 \|Bz \|^2 - |\langle By, Bz \rangle|^2}$ (of course this is just a conjecture at this point).